# PC speaker cable extension

Tags: cables, speakers

I have a 2.1 PC speaker system and I would like to know what are the disadvantages and advantages of extending both satellites cables using RCA cable extensions.

Each satellite has 16W. The amplifier is located in the subwoofer and each of the satellites are connected using ~150 cm long cables with RCA connectors on the subwoofer. I don't know the AWG of the satellite cable, all I know is that the cable is about as thick as a PC mouse or PC keyboard cable.

Later edit: The extension cables that I want to use are 150 cm long, which means that the entire cable from each of the speakers to amplifier will be ~300 cm long.

Also, would soldering a normal 2 wire cable (not shielded) with one end to a male RCA connector and the other end to a female RCA connector be a good way to make an extension for the speakers? In a photo I saw that the original cable is not shielded.

Comment: Using RCA connectors and speaker cable should work. Do not use standard RCA audio cables you can buy from stores, they are meant for line level audio signals and cannot handle the currents of speaker level signals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The centre core of a shielded cable will be lightweight and higher resistance. Unshielded would be better and shielding isn't required wen feeding a low impedance loudspeaker with a relatively high powered signal.